# Redirecting to a certain controller function if validation failed in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, construct

I am trying to redirect to controller index if not authorized the access to other functions within same controller. According to my coding it is looking like infinite loop. Please help me to do that.

```
class Customer_Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $method= $this->router->fetch_method();
        if ($this->session->userdata("cus_sel_comp")) {

        }else{
            if($method !="index"){
                redirect(base_url()."customer_dashboard");exit;
            }
        }
    }
    public function index() {
        // Here do some operations and let the user to select company and update the "cus_sel_comp" session variable. After set that session user can access the other controller functions.
    }
    public function other_function1() {

    }
    public function other_function2() {

    }
}
```

My coding is as above. I need to do this using same controller. Problem is if that session not set there is a infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting return index function. See the code below

```
 if($method !="index"){
              return $this->index();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the same function and redirecting it to same method.

```
    class Customer_Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct() {
            $method= $this->router->fetch_method();
            if ($this->session->userdata("cus_sel_comp")) {

            }else{
                if($method !="index"){
                    redirect(base_url()."Customer_Dashboard/index"); // Redirect it to index if other method is invoked.
                }
            }
        }
        public function index() {
            // Here do some operations and let the user to select company and update the "cus_sel_comp" session variable. After set that session user can access the other controller functions.
        }
        public function other_function1() {

        }
        public function other_function2() {

        }
    }
```

Also dont use `base_url()` instead of that define an path in config
`base_url()` has many other entries present which are un-necessarily called.

Comment: Can you give me a solution for that?

Comment: @GayanFernando have I answered your question regarding redirect?. Are you asking solution for that or `base_url` one?

Comment: I need to redirect to customer_dashboard controller index function. Not for the site main controller. Is that possible to do? Or else is there a way to do that other than using redirect?

Comment: check the answer. I have redirected it to index of customer_dashboard index function